# T-SQL - how do I get this result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how do I get the following result set...

```
Desc0, Desc1,      ,Desc2                ,Desc3             , Desc4
ASSETS,Fixed Assets,Tangible Fixed Assets,Land and Buildings, Equipment
ASSETS,Fixed Assets,Tangible Fixed Assets,Vehicles          , Null
```

if the source table looks like this...

```
Desc, type

ASSETS, 0
Fixed Assets,   1
Tangible Fixed Assets,  2
Land and Buildings, 3
Operating Equipment 4, 
Vehicles,   3
```

I tried this...

```
`SELECT  case when type=0 then Name else null end report_type, 
    case when type=1 then Name else null end account_level_1, 
    case when type=2 then Name else null end account_level_2,
    case when type=3 then Name else null end account_level_3,
    case when type=4 then Name else null end account_level_4,
    case when type=5 then Name else null end account_level_5
from [dbo].[Account]`
```

Comment: `if the source table looks like this...` ... your source table only has 6 points of data, but your expected result set has 9.  Please edit your question to bring the sample data inline with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `row_number()` & do conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when [type] = 0 then [desc] end),
       max(case when [type] = 1 then [desc] end),
       max(case when [type] = 2 then [desc] end),
       max(case when [type] = 3 then [desc] end)
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [type] order by [desc]) as seq
      from [dbo].[Account] a
     ) a
group by seq;
```